# How can I get attributes from complex SOAP::DATA structure in SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl, soap

I can't get a simple attribute value from SOAP response using SOAP::Lite.
Below the code and output of SOAP::Data. I'm trying to get value of the attribute //response/dirn/attr/uuid

```
my $cm = new SOAP::Lite
  uri => 'http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/1.0',
  proxy => "https://10.0.0.1:8443/axl/";

my $res = $cm->getPhone(
  SOAP::Data->name(phoneName => 'SEP00270D3D7A4C'),
);

for my $i ($res->valueof('//device/lines/line')) {
  print Dumper($i);
  #print $i->{dirn}->{attr}->{'uuid'}."\n"; # line below give me an error
}
```

Here the output of Data::Dumper. I actually have the requested value, but I can't get it through SOAP::Data

```
$VAR1 = \bless( {
'_signature' => [],
'_value' => [
  bless( {
    '_name' => 'dirn',
    '_signature' => [],
    '_value' => [
      ''
    ],
    '_prefix' => '',
    '_attr' => {
      'uuid' => '{615C3550-1EFD-56C7-3788-2AA8725880E3}' #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
  }, 'SOAP::Data' ),
],
'_attr' => {}
}, 'SOAP::Data' );
```

I spent about several hours trying to get this attribute value. I've already thinking about using output of Data::Dumper to get the value as fast and dirty hack.

Thanks in advance

P.S.: SOAP Server is Cisco CUCM 6.1.5

Answer (score 0):

```
$$i->value->attr->{uuid}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i->{'_value'}[0]{'uuid'}
```

I think, though, I'm not sure about the [0].

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, but can not find an "quick and easy" solution to it. I developed a Perl library module to use certain vendor Web Service (WSDL). I had done many of such Web Service interfaces, but until now - all of the data was returned as XML "elements". On the contrary, this particular Web Service returns most of the data as XML elements, but also sets some - as XML attributes. I can not get values returned as attributes - since SOAP::Data methods (valueof(), body(), etc.) only return values of XML elements, but not associated attributes.

This problem is a little different from the one posted before - in that I do not know up front the XML structure that is being returned (given web service provides many different methods, and each - has different response).

So question is - how it is possible to get *all* of the XML data (both elements and attributes) for a generic response SOAP data

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing recently and found the answer, refer to my question and my updated answer in the comments section.
 [Extract specific XML element in CDATA taken from SOAP::Lite Response Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164438/extract-specific-xml-element-in-cdata-taken-from-soaplite-response-hash)